# dragging formula down with jumps of 6

Tags: excel

I have a huge worksheet in which I want to find nearest neighbor distances between 6 XYZ coordinates. To do this I use the formula:

```
=(($H$2-$H2)^2+($I$2-$I2)^2+($J$2-$J2)^2)^0.5
```

In which the double locked value the reference point is and the single locked value are the neighboring points (one value gives 0 because its the same as the refence point of course).

I have many groups of 6 of which I only have the XYZ coordinates.

How do I rewrite the above function so I can drag it down and use it for each of these groups?

Sorry if this is very unstructured, I'm kind of new to excel and really need help with this.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the table or at least a screenshot of it?

Comment: Added a screenshot, so what you see, I did all by hand. I want to be able to drag it down instead of rewriting after each 6 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in `R2`:

```
=((INDEX($H:$H,(ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/6,0)-1)*6+2)-$H2)^2+(INDEX($I:$I,(ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/6,0)-1)*6+2)-$I2)^2+(INDEX($J:$J,(ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/6,0)-1)*6+2)-$J2)^2)^0.5
```

The `-1` is caused by your headline, the `6` derives from each block's length.

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX and some math:

```
=((INDEX($H:$H,INT(ROW($ZZ1)-1)/6)*6+2)-$H2)^2+(INDEX($I:$I,INT(ROW($ZZ1)-1)/6)*6+2)-$I2)^2+(INDEX($J:$J,INT(ROW($ZZ1)-1)/6)*6+2)-$J2)^2)^0.5
```

Comment: You were once more faster and provided a shorter solution with `INT` instead of `ROUNDUP`. Well done!